# Pouchdb: db.allDocs({include_docs: true} construct not displaying details of doc

Tags: cloudant, pouchdb

I am trying to display the details of the documents inserted in PouchDB with

```
var docs = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {
}
```

but this does not seem to display the details of the document. Thew display is as shown below

```
{ total_rows: 6,
  offset: 0,
  rows:
 [ { id: 'book1', key: 'book1', value: [Object], doc: [Object] },
 { id: 'book2', key: 'book2', value: [Object], doc: [Object] },
 { id: 'book3', key: 'book3', value: [Object], doc: [Object] },
```

The value and doc is still shown as objects. The code is included below. I am not sure what I am missing. Please let me know.

```
var docs = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {   
var val = response.total_rows;
var value = "";
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
for(i=0; i < val; i++) {        
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.rows[i].id) + "\n");    
    res.write(JSON.stringify(response.rows[i].id) + "\n")'              
}
res.end();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into the doc property of each row in rows.
You should also notice, that total_rows give you the number of all docs in the db even if you limit the documents with startkey and / or endkey. You better use the forEach method of the array prototype.